# How to change the order of list elements in Firebase Real-time database (android-java)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase real-time database for my android app. There is a list that I display in a recycler view. I want the user to have the ability to change the order of the cards in the list.

I thought to create a sort key in each element(object) of the list and fetch data using the sort key. But that's too heavy on larger lists. Is there any simpler solution for this?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried and please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo